# Web Service to Html response

Tags: java, web-services, wildfly, resteasy, java-ee-7

I am trying to build a web service that responds to a browser. Do I have to return the `html` code as a hardcoded `string` or is there a better way? It's a simple authentication service that needs to direct to the main page of an exam. I am really confused with all the tutorials and answers around the net, everyone has a different way for implementing a web service. What am I missing here? I use RestEasy on Wildfly 13.

Html call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="resources/login/userlogin" >
            Username: <input type="text" name="Username">
            <br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="Password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Service:

```
@POST
@Path("userlogin")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

public String Authenticate(@FormParam("Username") String Username, @FormParam("Password") String Password) {
LoginToken token = LoginTokenSingleton.instance.getToken(Username, Password);
if (token == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("POST: User not found");
}
//return the html code for a succesfull login?
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking a `POST request` when you submit the form having the `username` and `password`.

Once the user is authenticated in the backend you can return a `Success HTTP status code - 200` and on the basis of that you can redirect the user to the main page. And if the user is not authenticated you can send a `Not Authenticated Status Code 401` and redirect the user to some other page.

Comment: It worked with status code 303,not 200, probably because I used `Response.seeOther()`. I also changed the return type of the method to `Response` instead of `String`. For authenticating a desktop client I did the same but instead of redirecting I used `Response.ok().entity(myObject)`